# Is $\dfrac{\sin(A)}{2}= \sin \left (\dfrac{A}{2}\right)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I was wondering if $\dfrac{\sin(A)}{2}= \sin \left (\dfrac{A}{2}\right)$ and please explain why or why not.

Comment: Did you plug in some values of $A$ and see if equality holds?

Comment: It can or cannot be depends upon the angle A say it is 2nπ then the eqation is  true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a geometric view of $why?$ and $why$ $not?$

Red one : $\frac{\sin(x)}{2}$

Blue one : $\sin(\frac{x}{2})$

[image]

Comment: You have the labels reversed:  Your red graph has an amplitude of $1/2$ and period $2\pi$, which corresponds to $y = \frac{1}{2}\sin x$.  Your blue graph has amplitude $1$ and period $4\pi$, which corresponds to $y = \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$.

Comment: Yes yes ! I see.. thanks for correcring me.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not take for example $$A=\pi$$